# If inverse images are same then functions are same

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $f,g:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ such that $f^{-1}((a,\infty))=g^{-1}((a,\infty))$ for all $a\in\Bbb Q$. Prove that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$.

Attempt: Suppose that $f(x)\neq g(x)$. Without loss of generality $f(x)>g(x)$.
Let $f^{-1}((a,\infty))=g^{-1}((a,\infty))=A$ then $(a,\infty)=f(A)$ and $(a,\infty)=g(A)$.
Thus, $f(x)-g(x) >0$ does not hold for $x\in A$. This contradicts the fact that $f(x)\neq g(x)$.

Is the solution correct?

Answer (score 1):

No. You did not say what $a$ is and it is also not true in general that $g(A)=(a,\infty)$.

Suppose $f(x) >g(x)$ and choose a rational number $a$ between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. Then $x \in f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ but $x \notin g^{-1}(a,\infty)$. This contradicts the hypothesis.